# How to calculate payment from user's registration date plus 30 days IN ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to calculate payments by a certain period.

Specifically, I wonder if the user registered on the x date, how much payment he has in 30 days from that date

There are two tables:

```
create table user (user_id, contact, registration_date) as
    select 1,   111 111, 1/18/2022 3:57:32 PM from dual union all
    select 2, 222 222,    8/12/2021 12:00:12 AM from dual union all
    select 3, 333 333,  12/11/2015 5:08:35 PM  from dual union all
    select 4, 444 444,  5/25/2020 10:59:10 AM  from dual;



create table transaction (day, user_id, payment) as
 select   1/20/2022,   1, 5 from dual union all
 select    1/30/2022, 1,  8  from dual union all
 select   2/20/2022, 1,  6  from dual union all
 select  8/12/2021 , 2,  10  from dual union all
 select  8/15/2021 , 2,  5  from dual union all
 select  9/25/2021 , 2,  12  from dual union all
 select  12/11/2015 , 3,  18  from dual union all
 select  12/20/2015 , 3,  10  from dual union all
 select  1/1/2016 , 3,  10  from dual union all
 select  5/26/2020 , 4,  7  from dual union all
select  6/1/2020 , 4,  2  from dual;
```

I wonder something like this, but this query does not work,

```
select t.user_id,u.registration_date,sum(t.payment) from transaction t
left join user u on t.user_id = u.user_id
where t.day >= u.registration_date and t.day <= u.registration_date + interval '30' days
group by t.user_id
```

My expected table:

| user_id | registration_date | payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/18/2022 3:57:32 PM | 13 |
| 2 | 8/12/2021 12:00:12 AM | 15 |
| 3 | 12/11/2015 5:08:35 PM | 38 |
| 4 | 5/25/2020 10:59:10 AM | 9 |

Comment: Why do you *outer* join user to transaction? Are there transactions without a user and you want to have these in your results? This doesn't seem likely. And why join the user table at all? What do you want to get fro this table that you don't find in the transactions? Did you want it vice versa maybe; get users, too, that have no transaction?

Comment: And please don't ever say "but this query does not work" without telling us in what way it does not work. Does it throw an error? If so, which? Does it return too many rows or too few or wrong sums or ...?

Comment: [**ORA-00937**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): **Cause**: A SELECT list cannot include both a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, and an individual column expression, unless the individual column expression is included in a GROUP BY clause.

**Action**: Drop either the group function or the individual column expression from the SELECT list or add a GROUP BY clause that includes all individual column expressions listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you probably want to outer join the transactions to the users not vice versa. Thus you also show users with no trasactions in the 30 days after registration.

Then, Oracle requires you to either put `u.registration_date` in `GROUP BY` or pseudo aggregate it (e.g. `MIN(u.registration_date)`). This doesn't comply with standard SQL, but it seems that Oracle hasn't mananged yet to properly detect functional dependencies, so they simply don't offer this feature.

At last, the registration date, despite its name, is not a date but a datetime. In order to compare it with the transaction date, truncate it. Then decide whether you want to include the 30th after the registration date or not (i.e. either add 30 or 31 days and use < anyway).

```
select u.user_id, u.registration_date, sum(t.payment) 
from users u
left join transactions t
       on t.user_id = u.user_id
       and t.day >= trunc(u.registration_date) 
       and t.day < trunc(u.registration_date) + interval '31' day
group by u.user_id, u.registration_date
order by u.user_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a6d8d13c994eff6a1c0f8afa6fcb176f

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
SQL>   SELECT u.user_id, u.registration_date, SUM (t.payment) payment
  2      FROM tuser u JOIN transaction t ON t.user_id = t.user_id
  3     WHERE t.day BETWEEN u.registration_date
  4                     AND u.registration_date + INTERVAL '30' DAY
  5  GROUP BY u.user_id, u.registration_date
  6  ORDER BY u.user_id;

   USER_ID REGISTRATI    PAYMENT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 01/18/2022         13
         2 08/12/2021         15
         3 12/11/2015         38
         4 05/25/2020          9

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't work because you forgot to add the u.registration_date in your GROUP BY clause. When you do a GROUP BY, all fields mentioned in the SELECT need to be either added to the GROUP BY or be used in a aggregate function like SUM, MIN, MAX, ...